# Translate multiple models in Forge Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I want to translate multiple models using the Forge API. Currently we are able to translate a single model successfully. 
Our requirement is to load multiple models in the Forge viewer. For that we need to translate multiple files in the Forge Model Derivative API.

Answer (score 2):

To translate multiple models, is the same as translating a single model in your Forge Bucket storage.
Once you have created the SVFs, grab their URNs and load multiple models into the Forge Viewer using this blog post as your guide:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

The trick is to set this Viewer option...

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables,{ 
     keepCurrentModels: true,
     ...etc
```

Let me know if that helps
Cheers
Michael